# Powershell arrays - Get upper and lower index value before joining

Tags: arrays, powershell, indexing, find, mergesort

I have a two PowerShell objects that I parse: $Table1 and $Table2.
Parsing Table 1, I get a Timestamp: $TimeStamp for which I need to find the two closest values in Table 2.

```
$Table2 looks like this:


Price  TimeStamp       
-----  ----------------       
0.0597 1542056680.72746
0.0584 1542056650.34414
0.0555 1542056197.46668
0.0551 1542056167.28967

$TimeStamp = 1542056303
$Table2 is already sorted by TimeStamp
```

My goal is to get **back efficiently the upper and lower indexes of $Table2** (core of my question). I will then make a linear interpolation between the two timestamps and the two prices to get the value of $Price.

The linear interpolation part is not required in the answer, this is just for context purpose.

Cheers,

Philippe

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like that:

```
$TimeStamp = 1542056303

# find closest before given timestamp
$Table2 | Where-Object { [int]$_.Timestamp -gt $TimeStamp } | Select-Object -Last 1

# find closest after given timestamp
$Table2 | Where-Object { [int]$_.Timestamp -lt $TimeStamp } | Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: Since the table is sorted descending, you've to exchange `-lt` <=> `-gt` otherwise you'll get the very first and very last entry instead of the nearest.

Answer (score 1):

Imo you don't need the index if you store the row.

- iterating the table and check if current value less or equal than $TimeStamp
- if not store current row as $Upper
- if `-le` store row as $Lower and break the foreach

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\13\SO_53279995.ps1

$TimeStamp = 1542056303
$table2 = Import-Csv '.\table2.csv' | Sort-Object TimeStamp -Descending
$Upper = $Null
$Lower = $Null

ForEach ($Row in $table2){
    if([Double]$Row.TimeStamp -le $TimeStamp){
        $Lower = $Row
        Break
    } else {
        $Upper = $Row
    }
}
If ($Upper -and $Lower){
    $Upper
    $Lower
    "Do your interpolation"
} else {
    "can't evaluate nearest values"
}
```

Sample output

```
Price  TimeStamp
-----  ---------
0.0584 1542056650.34414
0.0555 1542056197.46668
Do your interpolation
```

Comment: Works great ! Thanks !!! I wanted to use the index for better performance, but this is not too much the issue here :-)